# a simple notification system for asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

hi i am coding my website that is an e-learning management system ( i hope ).
my database has different tables like users, Lessons , fields , Files , branches , groups , city , university and ... ( using `msSql`)
now i need an notification system ( not important to be real time ) to notify  users when a new user join or a new branch or... are added to  database. 
now i want to ask that what is the best way to gather this information and show these info
for example on something like a `GridView` or `DataList`.
i decided to create a notification table to save this changes but i think its not a  good way.
please help me to chose the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already seem to be in the MS stack I would suggest SignalR to maintain your notifications. That way you can handle notification to anyone that is currently logged on (because real time is usually better for anything collaborative). SignalR has a lot of examples available for implementing updates on your website.
For any users not logged in, simple hold their previous login datetime and send them any updates (you can create a quick view for this info sorted by updatetime) that have happened since their last login.
Hope that at least points you in the right direction.